# What are some commonly used non-threshold dependent classification predictive performance metrics?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-evaluations, scoring

I'm working on a prediction framework that utilizes a classification algorithm, trained on data with a binary outcome, and makes probabilistic predictions. I'm looking for some help determining appropriate metrics to evaluate and score the predictive performance of my framework. I'm familiar with threshold dependent metrics such as Accuracy, Precision, Recall, F1 Score, and ROCAUC (less threshold dependent, but still uses thresholds as a concept), however, the clients that use my framework rely on the probabilities generated as a response, meaning we don't utilize or rely on a binary prediction (which would be the probabilities compared against some threshold) and are not interested in evaluating ranking performance.

I'm looking for commonly used approaches for evaluating the predictive performance of a classification model using the probability outcomes (probability estimation performance). I'm familiar with log loss, but am hoping to find more interpretable metrics that can be used to establish baseline model performance as well as compare performance across different test sets (for example, in an online scoring process).

I'm currently using log loss which is solving some use cases, but not very interpretable for non-technical stakeholders and really only useful when comparing multiple models on the same test set.